# PHP - check if string contains "youtube" then display

Tags: php

I have a string which outputs user provided URLs.
I'm trying to display only the output which contains youtube videos.
So I use the below code as per usual :

```
<?php 
$a = $user[youtube1];
if (strpos($a, 'youtube.com') !== false) { ?>
```

However non-youtube URL still appear.
I'd appreciate any help with this. Maybe i'll have a lightbulb moment tomorrow morning.

Comment: Please provide false-positive examples

Comment: Is `youtube1` a constant? If it isn't, then your code will not run without either `Warning: Use of undefined constant youtube1 - assumed 'youtube1'`, or `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "youtube1"` in PHP 8. If you're manually copying code from your editor into your question, then please update your question with _pasted_ code. Also, please post more than you've done, as a lot of context is now missing.

Comment: 'youtube1' is a non-constant PHP variable which outputs the user provided URL.
So I please require PHP for :

If youtube1 contains string 'youtube' then display else none.

I've used the same code elsewhere on the website which works.

Comment: That's exactly what your code is doing. So you need to give us a concrete value that fails to meet the condition to see what the problem is.

Comment: The URL below contains 1 iframe embed (non-youtube). When I wrap the code in the above code , all iframe URL's still render.

https://www.purelocal.com.au/search-it-local-online-digital-marketing-google-ranking

Comment: Ok I had to apply the ltrim to make it work (if other users read this , try :
<?php if (strpos(trim($user[youtube1]), 'youtube') !== false) { ?>

Answer (score 0):

If PHP variable outputs string containing "youtube" then display else none , code :

```
<?php if (strpos(trim($user[youtube2]), 'youtube') !== false) { ?>  
Content here if youtube2 variable contains 'youtube' in output
<?php } ?>
```

Note : applying 'trim' here worked but may not be necessary in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, but you can simplify the expression a bit:

https://paiza.io/projects/D-wItdFAGLJxr9d6ttZAEA

```
<?php

$url1 = 'https://www.youtube.com';
$url2 = 'https://www.google.com';

echo isYouTubeURL($url1) ? 'true':'false';
echo "\r\n";
echo isYouTubeURL($url2) ? 'true':'false';

function isYouTubeURL($url){
  return strpos($url, 'youtube.com');
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```